# Combining 3 VBA macros into 1 (2 delete rows on different sheets, and 1 refreshes data)

Tags: vba, excel

I have 3 macros that I would like to combine into one that runs sequentially. The first bit I would like to run refreshes all of the data in an excel workbook, the next two delete specific rows on a sheet. The three macros I have work individually, but I would like to combine all three so the end user can run them all at once. I think the issue I'm running into is that I incorrectly made these macros to run on specific sheets, not modules. I'm stuck on combining them, since the macros are already in different sheets.

The First Macro:

```
Sub Macro1()
   ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
   Sheets("ManagementDashboard").Select
End Sub
```

The Second Macro (Runs in the sheet named "RawDataPltzr")

```
Sub DeleteRows()
   Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "c").End(xlUp).Row
   For i = Last To 1 Step -1
           'if cell value is less than 100
   If (Cells(i, "c").Value) < 100 Then
           'delete entire row
        Cells(i, "c").EntireRow.Delete
     End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

The Third Macro (Runs in the sheet named "RawDataLoader", also the same as 2nd macro, just has to run in different sheet)

```
Sub DeleteRows()
  Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "c").End(xlUp).Row
  For i = Last To 1 Step -1
            'if cell value is less than 100
    If (Cells(i, "c").Value) < 100 Then
            'delete entire row
        Cells(i, "c").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

At the end, I want the sheet "ManagementDashboard" to be selected, like in the first macro, but I need the second and third macro to run before it does so. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Fully qualify your sheet references. The way the code is now, it assumes ActiveSheet, which can cause a lot of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only code relating to worksheet events should be in the worksheet modules

1. Create a new module (right click > insert > module)
2. Move all three subs into the new module (rename those with the same name)
3. Anywhere you have `Cells` you need to refer to the appropriate worksheet first. E.g. `Worksheets("RawDataLoader").Cells()`
4. Add a new sub as per below which will run all 3 for you

---

```
Sub RunAll()
    Macro1
    DeleteRowsPltzr
    DeleteRowsLoader
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ManagementDashboard").Activate    
End Sub
```

Make sure you understand that method properly. At which point you can combine all three subs into this one sub (no need to call them separately)

```
Sub RunAll()
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("RawDataPltzr", "RawDataLoader"))
        Last = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "c").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = Last To 1 Step -1
                  'if cell value is less than 100
          If (ws.Cells(i, "c").Value) < 100 Then
                  'delete entire row
              ws.Cells(i, "c").EntireRow.Delete
          End If
        Next i
    Next ws

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ManagementDashboard").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works great!

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you don't reference a location excel takes whatever is active at the time and runs with it. For example `Cells(i, "C").EntireRow.Delete` is read as `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveWorksheet.Cells(i,"C").EntireRow.Delete`. By using `Dim` we don't have to select or active any worksheets or cells. Reference [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/5994620) for more information. I left the final `.Activate` in there but it's very bad practice to use. Throw this code into its own module and it should run fine.

```
Sub All_Three()

    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim MD As Worksheet, RDP As Worksheet, RDL As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long, i As Long, myCount As Long

    Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook
    Set MD = wbk.Worksheets("ManagementDashboard")
    Set RDP = wbk.Worksheets("RawDataPltzr")
    Set RDL = wbk.Worksheets("RawDataLoader")

    'Macro1
    wbk.RefreshAll

    For myCount = 1 To 2
        Select Case myCount
            Case 1
                Set ws = RDP
            Case 2
                Set ws = RDL
        End Select

        'Macro 2 and 3
        With ws
            Last = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            For i = Last To 1 Step -1
                If .Cells(i, "C").Value < 100 Then
                    .Cells(i, "C").EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            Next i
        End With
    Next myCount

    MD.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: You might be interested in using arrays of  worksheet names to avoid the counter and select statement (see my answer)

Comment: @CallumDA I completely agree. When I first got into VBA arrays broke my brain for awhile. I wanted to keep this more simple for someone else who was starting.